# WinForms UserControl Designer for Control[] Property

Tags: c#, winforms, designer, windows-forms-designer

If I have a public property for the designer of type Control I see a dropdown of controls that currently exist.

However, if I have a Control[] I can only create new controls.  Is it possible to somehow be able to choose existing Controls for the Control[] property via Designer?

[image: http://i55.tinypic.com/2j14xvo.png]

I have the following:

```
[Browsable(true),CategoryAttribute("Text"), DescriptionAttribute("Tooltips for underlined text")]
public Control[] TooltipControls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an Control[] through an additional class:

```
/// <summary>
/// A cass component that linking controls.
/// </summary>
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public class LinkControl : Component
{
    private Control m_pControl;

    public Control Control
    {
        get => m_pControl; 
        set
        {
            m_pControl = value;

            //If we're in designer mode, we'll set a name for the link object.
            if (this.Site != null && this.Site.DesignMode)
            {
                Site.Name = "m_pLink_" + value.Name;
            }
        }
    }

    public LinkControl( )
        : base( )
    {
        m_pControl = null;
    }
}
```

And in your control:

```
public class MyControl
{
    public List<LinkControl> Controls {get; set;}

    ...
}
```

[In designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5zuA.png)